# Getting selected radio button value here

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html in my form that looks like this. First, is this code malformed or something? Second, when the selected radio changes, how do I get the value of the selected radio? I do `$('#form_options').change(function(){ });` but what goes inside to get the value of the selected button

```
<div id="form-options">
   <label for="options">Choose an option</label>

   <Label for="morning">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="options-morning" value="morning" />Morning
   </label> 
   <label for="options-night">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="options-night" value="night" />Night
   </label>
   <label for="options-evening">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="options-evening" value="evening" />Evening
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use the change event for radiob buttons because it is inconsistent across browsers (try it in say IE 8), use click instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your div id is wrong. You need `$('#form-options')` instead of `$('#form_options')`

Try this:

```
$('#form-options').change(function() {
    alert($('input[name=options]:checked').val());
});
```

You can try it here - http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/PF8qX/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("input[@name='options']", '#form-options').change(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```